# Pyspark function works properly by itself but does not perform the task when wrapped in a UDF

Tags: python, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have this function that takes in a code and checks if the code is used (ie: is in used_codes dict). If it has not been used then it spits out that same code if it has been used then it generates a new code. Then I am creating a new df with this new column "code_id" of all unique codes.

My function is working properly by itself but when it goes through the udf it does not do the task. My used_codes dict is empty even though I have a ton of repeat codes that should have been added to used and then replaced.

I'm not sure why it works before it is wrapped in a UDF but not when ran as a UDF.

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import random

data = [("James", "36636"),
    ("Michael", "36636"),
    ("Robert", "42114"),
    ("Maria", "39192"),
    ("Jen", "39192")
  ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("id", StringType(), True), \
  ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)

used_codes = {}

def generate_random_code():
        random_number = random.randint(10000,90000)
        return random_number

def get_valid_code(code):
    global used_codes
    if(code != "" and code not in used_codes.keys()):
        used_codes[code] = 1 
        return code
    new_code = generate_random_code()
    while (new_code in used_codes.keys()):
        new_code = generate_random_code() 
    used_codes[new_code] = 2
    return new_code

get_valid_code_udf = F.udf(lambda code: get_valid_code(code), T.StringType())

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)

new_df = df.withColumn("code_id", get_valid_code_udf('id'))

df.show()
+---------+-----+                                                               
|firstname|   id|
+---------+-----+
|    James|36636|
|  Michael|36636|
|   Robert|42114|
|    Maria|39192|
|      Jen|39192|
+---------+-----+

>>> new_df.show()
+---------+-----+-------+
|firstname|   id|code_id|
+---------+-----+-------+
|    James|36636|  36636|
|  Michael|36636|  63312|
|   Robert|42114|  42114|
|    Maria|39192|  39192|
|      Jen|39192|  76399|
+---------+-----+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the global variable `used_codes` in your function. This global variable **does not** exist in workers, that's probably why your function is not working as expected as a UDF, even though it **still** running well in each worker.

Comment: is there a work around for this?

Comment: you’d need to give us some sample input and expected output, that would help

Comment: I have edited the above - I created a df to show as an example and actually the function did work properly and it was not the UDF. It returned the new_df with unique codes. I guess the issue lies in when I am running this on an EMR. So my question now is, do you think the issue can be solved with a Multiprocessing Manager?